# How come my inform moderator flags just went up?

Tags: support, flags

I just noticed that instead of around 10 inform moderator flags remaining, I now have around 22. Why did the number go up?

Comment: Was there a sudden jump (ie; you had 10 yesterday, but suddenly you have got 22 flags for today)? Or you just didn't notice it all this while and it has gradually went up to 22?

Comment: i'm almost sure there was a sudden jump.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just mixing up meta flags and main flags? Flag count [depends on the ratio of helpful flags, and (at higher counts) reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117) - this means meta flags and main flags are calculated independently (their helpful flag counts are different).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this meta.SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117), the flag count is calculated as:

> - default 10 per day
> - one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
> - one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default
> - maximum 100

"Flag weight", although it [has been removed from the UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight), still exists in the backend. It's calculated as such:

> - start at 100
> - +10 for a flagged post (+5 for a comment) that we did something about (or was basically valid)
> - -10 for a flagged post (-5 for a comment) that we suppressed as invalid
> - min 0, max 750 (but non-linear above 500)
> - **IMPORTANT CHANGE** - if you flag so consistently badly that you reach 0 weight, flags will be suppressed

Therefore, if your flag weight has risen way beyond 100, you already get many new flags every day. :)

Comment: I've been at 44 for like... eons.

Comment: @Seth: The count of 100 includes Spam and Offensive Flags... Your total available flags should be 80+ by now (including Spam and Offensive ones)...

Comment: @Aditya Ahh, OK. I just got 45 regular and I have 40 spam, so yeah I have about ~85ish.